# Is Selenium suitable for use as an automation tool - as you would use cURL

Tags: selenium, curl, selenium-webdriver

For several reasons we cant use cURL to preform automated tasks on a 3rd party site, we've tried using selenium instead and via the php integration we can get it to work and preform the tasks we need.

Is there any downside to using Selenium for this purpose - after reading up about it i see its primary use seems to be as an automated testing tool, but could you see any reason not to use it as a part of a webapp.

The only obvious one that comes into mind is that if they change the pages html, but that would leave you in a similar position if you were using cURL and they changed the POST / GET data that needed to be received by the server..

Comment: I'm *really* curious as to why you cannot use `cURl`, `file_get_contents` or some other way already included in PHP

Comment: There is a load of encryption done on the POST data with js prior to being sent, in an ideal world we would work it back and be able to encrypt it ourselves, but for the amount of time involved this seems the simplest option.. unless if there are any particularly nasty downsides to it..

Comment: Fair enough. FWIW selenium is *not* an "automated *testing* tool". From their website: Selenium automates browsers. That's it. What you do with that power is entirely up to you. Primarily it is for automating web applications for testing purposes, **but is certainly not limited to just that.**

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does not change the HTML.

However, if you are going to try to use POST/GETs with Selenium, that would require a work around, if it is possible.

You are able to navigate webpages, go to URLs, look at the HTML, and execute javascript, if that is what you are looking to do with Selenium.

Comment: What i meant by if the html changes was that selenium checks for the id / class's of an element so if those changed it would not execute

Comment: Yes.  Selenium is able to select by id, class, css, xpath, tagname, and a few others that I can't think of at the moment.